# "export all" window blocks my plugins script UI

Tags: plugins, scripting, converters, maya, mel

I'm writing a custom File Translator for Maya which can export only (I have only declared the writer function).

Currently having a problem with the MEL script which defines the plugin's options as a GUI.

Currently I have a blank Maya scene, go to "file->export all". This creates the "File Export All" dialog, I then select my plugin exporter which runs my MEL script to create the bespoke options window. This new window is created behind the "File Export All" dialog and is not selectable!

Do I have to place my export plugin specific options within the export all dialog rather than placing them in a separate window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export all window is a modal window that is why your new window appears behind it.

You'll have to place the options in the export all dialog which will require you to edit the MEL script which actually draws it(not recommended). Rather you can make your own export window which uses the options provided by the [`file`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/Commands/file.html) command.